# Firebase not updating Current user Display name

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I"m using Firebase for Signup and login. I can successfully able to create account in Firebase but when user want to change the profile image and username, then I'm able to change profile image but display name remains same irrespective of any name I choose

Here is the code I"m using

```
                 UserProfileChangeRequest profleUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                            .setDisplayName("Newusername")
                            .setPhotoUri(uri)
                            .build();
```

and I have set task.sucessfull listener by using

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    // user info updated successfully
    showMessage("Sucessfully changed");
}
```

and I get ***Successfully changed*** response but when I move back to my profile activity, only new updated image is shown but display name remains same.

Here is the firebase version I"m using

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: That is a **very** old version of firebase-auth.  Consider updating.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to internal caching of Firebase. You can call `getCurrentUser().reload()` after the update is successful to manually refresh the data.

```java
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().reload()
```

According to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#reload())

> **public Task reload ()**
>
> Manually refreshes the data of the current user (for example, attached providers, display name, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're accessing userInfo with `id` of current user using `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser.getUid();`