# Issue with Updating User Profile in ReactJS using Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on a ReactJS project and using Firebase Authentication for user management. I have a component called CreatingAccount where users can provide their first name and last name to update their profile. I am using the useAuth hook from the AuthContext to get the current user.

However, I am facing an issue with updating the user's profile using the updateProfile function provided by Firebase. The function seems to be not working as expected, and the username is not getting updated.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "@/firebase/AuthContext";

function CreatingAccount() {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  const [firstname, setFirstname] = useState("");
  const [lastname, setLastname] = useState("");

  const changeUsername = async (newUsername) => {
    try {
      const user = currentUser;

      if (user) {
        await user.updateProfile({
          displayName: newUsername,
        });

        console.log('Username changed successfully.');
      } else {
        console.log('User not authenticated.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error occurred while changing the username:', error);
    }
  };

  async function handleSubmit() {
    console.log(firstname + '' + lastname);
    console.log(currentUser.username);
    console.log('after changing the name');
    const newusername = firstname + ' ' + lastname;
    changeUsername(newusername);
    console.log(currentUser.username);
  }

  return (
    // JSX code... its a form with name inputs and submit button
  );
}

export default CreatingAccount;
```

this is my firebase config file:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  //API KEYS
  // ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443304/firebase-not-updating-current-user-display-name?

Comment: yes i checked it but it doesnt seem to be the same with my problem , i tried using if (user) {
        await user.updateProfile({
          displayName: newUsername,
        });
but until now i still get errors so i dont know why is that?  i have aleady declared the auth in my useauth custom hook.

Comment: If you just navigate to different route of your application and then you go back to where the user name is, is it updated, or you need to refresh the page for it to get updated? Assuming that the `updateProfile()` is succsessful.

Comment: You can use the updateProfile() method for you to update a user's profile. You can check out this documentation for futher information needed on how to use the method of [updateProfile()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile")